# CSS for https urls

Tags: html, css, http, https

looking for some help with images referenced within the stylesheet. I have no problems with these from non secure locations within the site but only from https. The stylesheet loads fine and displays everything correctly except for the images.

```
example:

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url(/img/background_tile.gif) top left repeat-x;
text-align: center;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

All my css files and other image paths inside the code use relative urls to images. How can I make sure they all work fine without hard coding my image paths with https or http? I want the code to work fine with http and https.

Thanks

Comment: Is the CSS file served through HTTPS? I ask because urls in CSS are relative to the URL of the CSS file and not the calling page. What browser are you trying to view this in? Have you looked at the server access logs for errors?

Comment: Posting the link to your site might help. This is really just a guess and check game right now.

Comment: I am trying to view this in IE and firefox. Opera seems to render the css fine over https. My css files are included this way:
<link type="text/css" href="/design/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
IE screws up the entire rendering over https.

Comment: And are the images available via HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: Are the images available over HTTPS. Try just loading up the image URL over https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would open FireBug, look at the Net Tab, and see the HTTP status code for the image.

If the codes are 404, then I would look into the httpd.conf file (assuming you are using Apache) to see what the DocumentRoot is for your port 443 directives.

I say this knowing that is only kind of makes sense because if the 443 directive had a completely incorrect DocumentRoot then the entire site would not display. 
[image: FireBug Example]